# "Missing Body Element" with the Visual Web Pack on Netbeans

Tags: java, ide, netbeans, netbeans6.7

I am currently having an issue with the JSF pages that the Visual Web Package for Netbeans 6.7 generates.

When I generate a new page it produces a page with the following JSP code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<jsp:root version="1.2" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:ui="http://www.sun.com/web/ui">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=US-ASCII" pageEncoding="US-ASCII"/>
    <f:view>    
        <ui:page id="page1">
            <ui:html id="html1">
                <ui:head id="head1">

                    <ui:link id="link1" url="/resources/stylesheet.css"/>
                </ui:head>
                <ui:body id="body1" style="-rave-layout: grid">
                    <ui:form id="form1">
                    </ui:form>
                </ui:body>
            </ui:html>
        </ui:page>
    </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

However when I attempt to view it an error comes up with "Missing Body Element." This is quite frustrating.

I've spent many days googling for a solution for this and have run into nothing but dead ends. When Netbeans attempts to switch to design view this is logged in the error log:

```
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.netbeans.modules.visualweb.insync.faces.FacesPageUnit.findMarkupSectionElement(FacesPageUnit.java:665)
        at org.netbeans.modules.visualweb.insync.faces.FacesPageUnit.newCreatedBean(FacesPageUnit.java:597)
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is a problem that is being ignored, and won't be fixed for a while.