# visual web in netbeans 6.8

Tags: netbeans6.8

What happened to Visual web in Netbeans 6.8. Has the feature been removed?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any question in it or you have an issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was removed in 6.8.  Lots of people that use it are staying at 6.7.1.  The reason VW wasn't included is because that project is no longer being developed, and therefore won't be part of future NetBeans editions.

Comment: Its rather broken in 6.7.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652359/missing-body-element-with-the-visual-web-pack-on-netbeans

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely best that they just dropped it instead of continuing to ship broken code.

Answer (score 0):

It is an harakiri for Netbeans!!!
The reason i used netbeans instead of eclipse is the Visual web in Netbeans!!!
You should create another tool (a new Java Studio Creator) for those (we are a lot) that want to continue using this plugin!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Web Pack is an important feature and the main reason why we are using the netbeans ide instead of eclipse in our company for java web development. And now, you won't include this nice and very helpful tool in the future netbeans releases since 6.8? I think, netbeans will going down in the future, because now there is no reason to use this ide instead of eclipse. Good by Netbeans - we have a good time :(